# Android: Use AsyncTask in multiple Activitys

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am currently wondering how to use AsyncTask in multiple Activitys without copying it.

I used [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) Guide to do it in one Activity and that worked just fine. But to load and use this information in more than one Activity seems to me like to much work. I tried to put my LoadUrl function into another Class and just pass my Textfield I want to be edited. But my App crashes when i start it. (I am not sure if this is the right approach )

```
public class LoadFromUrl {

public void loadAccountInfo(String key) {

    if( key != null ) {

        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute();

    }
}

private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //textView.setText(result);
    }

    // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
    // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
    // a string.
    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 500;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }

    // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }

}
}
```

and calling it in:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    selectedAccount.setKey("google.com");

    loadUrl.loadAccountInfo(selectedAccount.getKey());

}
```

All I want to do is, load the information of an URL and use this to fill my activitys (like multiple TextViews). Every activity uses different urls and structures.

Answer (score 0):

Create `DownloadWebPageTask` in a separate file, as a `public` `class`. Then override its constructor to pass anything you need (a textfield, key, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Put `DownloadWebPageTask` in a separate class. Then in onPostExecute, run a callback to the activity or fragment that will update its UI. This is done by having an activity implement a callback which is an inner interface inside the the `DownloadWebpageTask` (doesn't have to be an inner interface!). As you can see, the inner interface I put with your code is `WebpageCallbacks`.

This is your asynctask in another class (the spacing isn't perfect sorry...):

```
public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

/**
 * Any activity or fragment that implements WebPageCallbacks
 */
private WebPageCallbacks callbacks;

//start by referencing your activity to call onURLLoaded() for onPostExecute()
public DownloadWebpageTask(WebPageCallbacks callbacks) {
    this.callbacks = callbacks; //note: I think weak references are preferred though
}
//no changes here
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    try {
        return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
    }
}

// onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask by callback's onURLLoaded()
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //each activity or fragment will has a method to change their UI
    callbacks.onURLLoaded(result);
}

// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
// the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string. No changes here
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Any Activity or fragment that implements this will have
     * onURLLoaded() method to update its own UI.
     */
    public interface WebpageCallbacks {

        void onURLLoaded(String result);
    }

}
```

I would then add `implements DownloadWebpageTask.WebpageCallBacks` to all your fragments and activities that will use this asynctask.

Here is your activity:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DownloadWebpageTask.WebpageCallBacks {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    selectedAccount.setKey("google.com");
    //changed your oncreate at line below to run your accountInfo
    runAccountInfo(selectedAccount.getKey());
}
    .......................

   //runs the asynctask to load url info from account info like your old loadURLInfo()
   public void runAccountInfo(String key) {

        if( key != null ) {
            //get url with getURL(key)
            new DownloadWebpageTask(this).execute(getURL(key));
        }
    }
    //this will be run from onPostExecute from the asynctask
    @Override
    public void onURLLoaded(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

If you have the time though, I suggest to not use `AsyncTask` at all and look into other libraries like rxJava/rxAndroid. I hope this code is ok........

Comment: I tried that out and got some errors for WebpageCallBack in my "DownloadWebpageTask.class" but i think i understood how the callback works. I will try that tomorrow again. Today i had not enough time to really see what went wrong
 
Thank you for the really long and good answer :)

Comment: Ah sorry about that... haha. If you're having the error, you can just make that an external interface